# What's wrong with this procedure of finding Lorentz transformation equations?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The velocity of light in vacuum is the same for all inertial observers. This means $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx'}{dt'}=c\\
\Rightarrow {(c\,dt)}^2-dx^2=0={(c\,dt')}^2-{dx'}^2.$$
I think that without further work, it is not obvious that for arbitrary nonzero values of ${(c\,dt)}^2-dx^2$, the equality
$${(c\,dt)}^2-dx^2={(c\,dt')}^2-{dx'}^2$$
will hold true.

**Given the postulate of the constancy of the speed of light, if we were to find how $(t,x)$ must transform, we can make use of the first equality only - a weaker condition than the second equality.** But it is usually derived using the stronger condition (second equality) which assumes the equality for arbitrary values of ${(c\,dt)}^2-dx^2$.

If we strictly have to follow the postulate, IMO, we must derive the Lorentz transformation equations in two steps as follows.

**Step 1.** First, we assume
$$c\,t'=A\,c\,t+B\,x,\quad x'=K\,c\,t+D\,x.$$

**Step 2** Then make use of two conditions ${(c\,dt')}^2-{dx'}^2=0$ and ${(c\,dt)}^2-dx^2=0$.

We start with
$${(c\,dt')}^2-{dx'}^2=0\\
\Rightarrow (A^2-K^2)\,c^2dt^2 + (B^2-D^2)\,dx^2 + 2(AB-KD)\,c\,dt\,dx=0$$
Now the only condition that we can use is $c\,dt=\pm dx$, which is insufficient to find all the four unknown constants.

Does this mean that one cannot derive the Lorentz transformation equations from the constancy of the speed of light only?

Comment: With $c>0$ and $dt>0$ you would have $cdt>0$, so your condition can only be $cdt=dx$ . A variable can not be positive and negative at the same time.

Comment: $dx/dt=\pm c$ implies light moving along $\pm x$ axis. Think about the light cone diagram. In fact, the first postulate implies $dx/dt=\pm c=dx'/dt'$.

Comment: You would then have to write $x_1=ct$ and $x_2=-ct$ . You can  not assume $x=ct$ and $x=-ct$ at the same time. You  might as well be saying that $1=-1$

Comment: I am not assuming that. I will use $dx=cdt$ and $dx=-cdt$, as two separate conditions. That's obvious. In any case, it doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the constancy of the speed of light is not sufficient.  You need additional assumptions. [These notes](http://www2.physics.umd.edu/%7Eyakovenk/teaching/Lorentz.pdf) by Victor Yakovenko provide a derivation of the general coordinate transformation

$$\pmatrix{x'\\t'}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+v^2/a}} \pmatrix{1 & -v\\v/a & 1}\pmatrix{x\\t}$$

where $a$ is some parameter with dimensions of velocity squared. This derivation makes the following assumptions:

1. The coordinate transformation should be linear (you already assumed this in step 1)
2. Space is isotropic, so e.g. the length of a moving ruler is the same if it's moving to the left as if it were moving to the right
3. The composition of two transformations is another transformation
4. Transformations depend only on the relative velocity between frames

---

This yields 3 viable possibilities.  Either $a>0$, $a<0$, or $a\rightarrow \infty$ (the latter case results in the Galilean transformations).  However, if we **additionally** demand that there exists an invariant speed $c$ such that objects moving with speed $c$ in one frame are moving with the same speed in every other frame, then the **only** possibility is that $a = -c^2 < 0$.

There are many routes to the Lorentz transformations which make different assumptions, but the point of my answer is that the assumption of the constancy of the speed of light is *not* sufficient all by itself.  There must be other (reasonable) physically-motivated assumptions about the structure and symmetries of spacetime to go along with it.

Comment: $a$ should be $-c^2$ not $-1/c^2$

Comment: @Thomas Yep, thanks.

Comment: It's fun to see this since Yakovenko taught my c. mech course in grad school and so I saw him give precisely this derivation.

Comment: You said *if we additionally demand that there exists an invariant speed c such that objects moving with speed c in one frame are moving with the same speed in every other frame* . Objects don't actually move with the same speed in different reference frames, only light does. And the problem with the derivation you linked to is that there isn't really any way to bring in the speed of light in a natural way. It very much appears as a reverse engineered derivation to get the desired result.

Comment: @Thomas It's not clear what you mean by "there isn't really any way to bring in the speed of light in a natural way". Constancy of the speed of light is an independent assumption. The purpose of the derivation starting from the points 1. 2. 3. 4 is to demonstrate that it is possible to defer the assumption of the constancy of the speed of light to the very last step. That demonstrates the independency. It appears you qualify the choice between 3 possibilities as 'bringing in the speed of light in an unnatural way', but it's not clear how that should constitute something "unnatural".

Comment: @zeldredge He taught mine too  I believe you and I have met once or twice, in fact.

Comment: @Cleonis Choosing the possibility that suits you from the 3 options can not be called a derivation. There is no stringent reason given in http://www2.physics.umd.edu/%7Eyakovenk/teaching/Lorentz.pdf why the Galilei transformation should not be the solution.

Comment: @Thomas I am aware that massive objects move at different speeds in different frames. What I said was that **if** you want there to be an invariant speed, **then** that fixes $a$ to be minus the square of that speed. Empirically, we have observed that the universe we occupy does have such a speed - the speed of light - which is the final piece required in the derivation of the Lorentz transformation formula.

Comment: @Thomas RE that last comment - yes of course. The fact that such a speed exists is a physical, empirically-observed input to the derivation. This is physics, not mathematics, and physics is not axiomatic - empirical input is an absolute necessity in every derivation we have.

Comment: @Thomas erm... the whole point of the dervation is to demonstrate that constraints 1. 2. 3. 4. do not rule out Galilean transformation. There is only one way to establish which transformation is applicable: by physical experiment. The data from experiments point us one way or the other. Hypothesis: you are under the impression that it should be possible to rule out Galilean transformation by sheer logical reasoning. Dispellling such a notion is the very reason the derivation starting from constraints 1. 2. 3. 4. is valuable.

Comment: The point is that there is no physical input to the equations in that derivation. It is a mathematical coordinate transformation but it is not specified what these coordinates physically relate to. Do they relate to the the path of an object? Or do they relate to the path of a light signal? And why would you assume the solution would be the same in the two cases?

Comment: @Thomas My answer takes for granted that you know what an inertial reference frame is and what the corresponding coordinates specify, since that is the context in which the question was asked. Your questions are not unimportant, but the answers to them are prerequisites for this one.

Comment: @Cleonis Let me put it this way:   if we would not know anything about the speed of light at all, on what grounds would you conclude that we have to investigate the propagation of light signals in order to obtain an answer regarding the question how the coordinates of some object transform between two reference frames moving relatively to each other?

Comment: @Thomas Indeed: the properties of propagation of light arise as a *consequence*; they are not cause. The key concept is the metric of spacetime. The transition from newtonian dynamics to relativistic dynamics was a transition of how space-and-time are conceptualized: newtonian: Euclidean metric; relativistic: Minkowski metric. The Minkowski metric is the principle because it describes the nature of spacetime. The Minkowski metric expresses the following physical property: there is an upper limit to speed of *any* propagation. Both matter and propagation of waves are subject to that upper limit

Comment: @Thomas stackexchange is designed specifically to not be a threaded forum. The comment section is not for conversation. The recommended way to proceed is: if you find yourself writing a *question* in a comment section, then rewrite that question to submit it as a standalone question. (For context you can of course refer to the answer that triggered it.)

Answer (score -1):

I have seen the Lorentz transformation derived in a very similar way you approached it:

Let me first rewrite your final equation without the differentials (there is little point in using these if the speed of light is assumed as constant)

$$(1)\:\:\:(A^2-K^2)c^2t^2 +(B^2-D^2)x^2 +2(AB-KD)ctx =0$$

If you subtract furthermore the equation $c^2t^2-x^2=0$ from this you get

$$(2)\:\:\:(A^2-K^2-1)c^2t^2 +(B^2-D^2+1)x^2 +2(AB-KD)ctx =0$$

If that is supposed to be true for all x at given t, each of the coefficients to the different powers of x have to be zero separately, so

$$(3)\:\:\:A^2-K^2-1=0$$
$$(4)\:\:\:B^2-D^2+1=0$$
$$(5)\:\:\:AB-KD=0$$

Now additionally you obviously have to use the constraint that the primed and unprimed frames are moving relatively to each other (after all, that is why we are doing this in the first place).
So the additional conditions we have are
$$(6)\:\:\:x'=0 => x=vt$$
$$(7)\:\:\:x=0 => x'=-vt$$

Inserting this into your transformation
$$(8)\:\:\:x'=Dx+Kct$$
$$(9)\:\:\:ct'=Act+Bx$$

yields then
$$(10)\:\:\:K=-\frac{v}{c}D$$
$$(11)\:\:\:A=D$$
$$(12)\:\:\:B=K$$

Inserting this into (3) and (5) yields

$$(13)\:\:\:D^2(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})-1=0 => D=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
$$(14)\:\:\:B=-\frac{v}{c}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$.

---

However, there is in my opinion a problem with this derivation:

The quadratic equations that lead to Eq.(1)
$$(15)\:\:\: x^2=c^2t^2   ;\:\:\: x'^2=c^2t'^2$$
have the solutions
$$(16)\:\:\: x_1=ct   ;\:\:\: x_1'=ct'$$
$$(17)\:\:\: x_2=-ct   ;\:\:\: x_2'=-ct'$$

so

$$(18)\:\:\: x_2= -x_1$$
$$(19)\:\:\: x_2'= -x_1'$$

We can rewrite the transformation (8) for the two solutions as

$$(20)\:\:\:x_1'=Dx_1+Kct$$
$$(21)\:\:\:x_2'=Dx_2+Kct$$

However, by inserting (18),(19) into (21) we get

$$(22)\:\:\:-x_1'=-Dx_1+Kct$$ i.e.
$$(23)\:\:\:x_1'=Dx_1-Kct$$

which is inconsistent with (20) unless $K=0$ i.e. unless $v=0$, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The original equations which led to (1) include $ct' = Act + Bx$ and $x' = Kct + Dx$, which are not invariant under $(x,x')\rightarrow(-x,-x')$.

Comment: @J.Murray You are trying to find a linear transformation that is consistent with $x^2=c^2t^2$,    $x'^2=c^2t'^2$ The latter equations are invariant under $(x,x′)→(−x,−x′)$

Comment: Right ... but why would you expect your linear transformation to be?  $x^2=4$ is invariant under $x\rightarrow -x$, but $x=2$ obviously isn't, nor is $x=-2$.

Comment: @J.Murray You missed out the crucial part:  from $x'^2=4$ you have then also the two solutions $x_1'=2$ and $x_2'=-2$, that is the primed variable changes sign when the unprimed changes sign

Comment: I think perhaps *you* are missing the crucial part.  $x' = \gamma(x-vt)$ and $-x' = \gamma (-x -vt) \iff x' = \gamma(x+vt)$ are both perfectly valid boosts.  They're not the *same* boost, just as $x=2$ and $x=-2$ are not the same solutions to $x^2=4$.

Comment: @J.Murray Please see my edited answer which should clarify my point.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to require that both $x’=0$ and $x=0$. There is only one event for which $x$ and $x’$ are both zero, and it’s at $t=t’=0$.

Comment: @J.Murray *It doesn’t make sense to require that both x′=0 and x=0* Not sure why you are saying that such a requirement (or any requirement for that matter) was made. The equations as written above merely evaluate the transformation equation separately for a light signal on the positive and negative x-axis assuming that a light signal sent out at t=t'=0 propagates symmetrically to the origin in either reference frame (as required by the invariance principle for the speed of light). Please refer directly to the algebraic equations above in case you see any issues somewhere.

Comment: Your edit makes the misunderstanding more clear, and it's related to a question you asked in a comment to my answer.  The Lorentz transformations relate the coordinates of events in one frame to the coordinates of the same event in another.  If you want to express the trajectory of a particle (or a light ray) in a new frame, you need to transform both the position and time coordinates.  In other words, your conditions (18/19) should be $x_2(t) = -x_1(t)$ and $x_2'(t')=-x_1'(t')$.  Expressing $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ in terms of $t'$ resolve your issues. If you remain confused, you should ask [...]

Comment: [...] a new question about this, because comment threads are not meant for extended discussion.

Comment: @J.Murray I am not trying to discuss anything nor to ask any questions. I am just informing you that your comment does not address  my answer. If you had checked Eqs(16),(17), you would have seen the time dependence of $x_1'$ and $x_2$' and also that consequently (18),(19) hold independently of $t$ and $t'$'. Again, please stick to the equations above and do not conjure up some unrelated arguments.

Comment: And I am informing you that you are incorrect about that.  I have taken the liberty of explicitly explaining why and how in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124380/lorentz-transformations-etc), to which you are welcome to respond if you continue to think I am wrong.